# Getting the outer most delimiters in Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, vb.net, recursive-regex

Is there a way using regular expressions to get the text in between outermost delimiters?  I have a string here and want to get the text in between the outermost `{%%%` and `%%%}` delimiters:

```
Hello {%%%=Select(DepartmentID,1,{%%%=if(Gender="M","Mr.","Ms.")%%%}%%%} {%LastName%}
```

The text I want to get is:

```
=Select(DepartmentID,1,{%%%=if(Gender="M","Mr.","Ms.")%%%}
```

What would the the regular expression for that?  I know the text inside does not make much sense, this is just an example.

Comment: Why not `{%%%(.*)%%%}` and use `$1` ?

Comment: @EugenRieck that will fail if there are multiple sets of delimiters (not nested): `{%%%foo%%%} {%%%bar%%%}`

Comment: If code is an acceptable solution for this, consider using a stack to keep track of open and close delimiters.

Comment: @Sam Ah, I now see, that this is not ruled out in the OQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern will do a positive lookahead:

```
[^%=]*.{%%%(.+)%%%}.+[^%}]*
```

capture group:

```
$1
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/eG4fV9

EDIT: It seems some people enjoy coming along after an answer was chosen as `correct` then adding possible scenarios where it won't work. That's fine, however, depending on the circumstances in which something is used can make anything `incorrect`.

original answer:

```
(?<={%%%=).+(?=}%%%)[^%]
```

optional:

```
[^%=]*.{%%%=(.+)%%%}.+[^%}]*
```

This will retain the `=` sign in the matches.

Comment: That almost works, but it is leaving the %%% in the found string

Comment: This is still incorrect; the closing delimiter is `%%%}`, not `}%%%`.  You'll need to get rid of the `[^%]`, too.

Comment: @Chris Given the requirements you set in the question, the solution you picked is definitely incorrect. For instance this regex does not match {%%%=abcd%%%} It doesn't match {%%%=ab{%%%=abcd%%%}cd%%%} either.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you can't find some unique feature to the delimiters (such as Eugen Rieck noted in comments - it's a good specific solution <strike>if he only changed it to non-greedy</strike>), the standard regular expressions can't do it.

Some regular expression engines, like Ruby's Oniguruma, can, by using recursive regexps. Something like (off the top of my head):

```
/{(?<braced>[^{}]*(?:{\g<braced>}[^{}]*)?)}/
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/Z6b5hkJUPJ)

Comment: And the reason for this (as far as I know) is because regex can't really "count".  You would have to say, here's the first open, second open, second close, first closed.

Comment: The greedyness is necessary to step over closing inner delimiters, but as @Sam pointed out, parallell constructs are not ruled out in the OQ.

Comment: @EugenRieck: Ah, right. I didn't notice inner ones are %%% also. So yeah, best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `/.*?\{\%\%\%(.*)\%\%\%\}.*/`

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FsF4d/1/)

Comment: JavaScript regexp does support greedy vs non-greedy. `.*` matches will be as large as possible `.*?` matches will be as small as possible

Answer (score 0):

Chris, here are two options that match what you're looking for, using recursive regex:

Option 1:

```
\{((?:[^{}]++|(?R))*)\}
```

Option 2:

```
\{(([^{}]*+)(?:(?R)(?2))*)\}
```

This is PCRE syntax, which works for instance in PHP.

What language and regex engine are you using? These patterns can be adapted to a few other flavors that support recursion.

Comment: zx81, I am using regex in VB.net